# Why doesn't this for-comprehension, starting with Option, compile in Scala?

Tags: scala, for-loop, monads, scala-collections, option-type

Given these definitions:

```
val guys = List("Albert", "Tom")
val girls = List("Mary", "Stacy", "Josie")

val optRoom: Option[String] = Some("Room 303")
```

This evaluates to me expected `List[String]`:

```
for {
  guy <- guys
  girl <- girls
  room <- optRoom
} yield {
  s"$guy dances with $girl in $room"
}
```

Turning things a bit inside the loop, I would expect this to evaluate to an `Option[List[String]]`, but it does not even compile:

```
for {
  room <- optRoom
  guy <- guys
  girl <- girls
} yield {
  s"$guy dances with $girl in $room"
}
```

Why not? What am I missing? (I know I can convert `optRoot` to a sequence / list / iterable, but it's not what I want)

How should I rewrite my code to get `Option[List[String]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is equivalent to

```
optRoom flatMap { room =>
  guys flatMap { guy =>
    girls map { girl =>
      s"$guy dances with $girl in $room"
    }
  }
}
```

Which doesn't work because you're not returning an `Option` to `optRoom.flatMap`.

If you want an `Option[List[String]]`, then you want to be calling `optRoom.map`, not `flatMap`, because you want the result wrapped in an `Option`:

```
for {
  room <- optRoom
} yield for {
  guy <- guys
  girl <- girls
} yield {
  s"$guy dances with $girl in $room"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You say: " because you're not returning an `Option` to `optRoom.flatMap`". Would it be possible to do so? Would it make sense?

Comment: It would make sense if the result you're calculating in the case `optRoom` is not `None` is naturally an `Option[something]`. In your case it's naturally a `List[String]`. So you could turn that into `Some[List[String]]`, but that is just using `flatMap` to emulate `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
optRoom.map(room => for {
  guy <- guys
  girl <- girls
} yield s"$guy dances with $girl in $room")
```

Your 2nd `for` gets roughly translated to:

```
optRoom.flatMap(room => guys.flatMap(guy => girls.map(girl => s"$guy dances with $girl in $room")))
```

Since you have `optRoom.flatMap(room => ...)` it is expected that the parameter is a Function from `String => Option[B]`, but `guys.flatMap(...)` is not of type `Option`.